# Q: In the context provided, is the formal parameter and object considered a local variable?

Tags: java, parameters, local-variables

I'm still learning the basics of CS, and while I know what a formal parameter and object is, I'm wondering if I can ever classify them as local variables.

For example, if I was in a class Foo:

```
private void bar(int x) { 

   x = x + 5; 
   Foo foo1 = new Foo();
   foo1.doCrazyStuff(); 

}
```

Would I still refer to the x's in the method definition as the formal parameter, or would I refer to x as a local variable since its value would disappear once the stack frame goes away? Is it appropriate to consider foo1 a local variable as well?

Comment: `foo1` **is** a local variable. `x = x + 5;` is an abuse of parameters. Too bad they didn't decide to make all parameters final.

Comment: Yes. both `x` and the reference `foo1` are local variables. I suggest using `javap -v yourClassName` from cmd line and checking the *local variable table*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the various [variable types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3) defined by the Java Language Specification:

According to this classification `x` is a *method parameter* and `foo1` is a *local variable*.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it appropriate to consider foo1 a local variable as well?

Yes and no.

Parameters are in effect local variables.

But it would be more appropriate to make them `final` and not use them as such.